# MySQL update table based on another tables value

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a two tables,

Here is my first table,

```
ID      SUBST_ID        CREATED_ID
1       031938          TEST123
2       930111          COOL123
3       000391          THIS109
4       039301          BRO1011
5       123456          COOL938
...     ...             ...
```

This is my second table,

```
ID      SERIAL_ID       BRANCH_ID
1       039301          NULL
2       000391          NULL
3       123456          NULL
...     ...             ...
```

I need to some how update all rows within my second table using data from my first table.

It would need to do this all in one update query.

Both SUBST_ID and SERIAL_ID match, it needs to grab the created_id from the first table and insert it into the second table.

So the second table would become the following,

```
ID      SERIAL_ID       BRANCH_ID
1       039301          BRO1011
2       000391          THIS109
3       123456          COOL938
...     ...             ...
```

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE2
       JOIN TABLE1
       ON TABLE2.SERIAL_ID = TABLE1.SUBST_ID
SET    TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID;
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error while using this solution. 'Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.'

Comment: I modified the query with where condition but still same error. QUERY: update contract c join contractstatus cs set c.status=cs.status where cs.contract=c.id;

Comment: Is there any way to do this without disabling safe mode in mysql.

Comment: You need to define an Index for the columns that you need to update and then the error and then he safe mode error will be gone

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Tom's answer if you need to **repeat the operation frequently** and want to **save time** you can do:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
       JOIN TABLE2
       ON TABLE1.SUBST_ID = TABLE2.SERIAL_ID
SET    TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID
WHERE TABLE2.BRANCH_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE TABLE2
       JOIN TABLE1
       ON TABLE1.SUBST_ID = TABLE2.SERIAL_ID
SET    TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID 
WHERE TABLE2.BRANCH_ID IS NULL or TABLE2.BRANCH_ID='';
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: by using  join on subset_Id and Serial_Id you will get a Result set.and that result set will contain created id..now Concentrate on query after SET there we actually assigning or providing values from created_Id to Branch_Id ....hope you understand.. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work

```
UPDATE secondTable
JOIN firsTable ON secondTable.SERIAL_ID = firsTable.SUBST_ID
SET BRANCH_ID = CREATED_ID
```

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple to update using Inner join query in SQL .You can do it **without** *using* `FROM` clause. Here is an example :

```
    UPDATE customer_table c 

      INNER JOIN  
          employee_table e
          ON (c.city_id = e.city_id)  

    SET c.active = "Yes"

    WHERE c.city = "New york";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.SUBST_ID = TABLE2.SERIAL_ID
SET TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID;
```

Another alternative solution like below: Here I am using `WHERE` clause instead of `JOIN`

```
UPDATE 
    TABLE1,
    TABLE2
WHERE
    TABLE1.SUBST_ID = TABLE2.SERIAL_ID
SET 
    TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too:

```
update TABLE1 set BRANCH_ID = ( select BRANCH_ID from TABLE2 where TABLE1.SUBST_ID = TABLE2.SERIAL_ID)
```

but with my experience I can say that this way is so slow and not recommend it!