# MySQL Update with 2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I have some rows with same 'stock_id', and need update with 2 conditions, but don't work, just update all rows with value 1

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE stock_table SET size = IF(kit = \'n\', 1, (1 * 10)) WHERE id = '.$row->stock_id);
```

But my size have S - M - X with same stock_id

Eg: I need update qtde column where stock = 13 and size = S

Comment: what two conditions? I only see one 'id = X'.

Comment: `1 * 10` is just `10`.

Comment: @danblack The other condition is the `IF()`

Comment: Are you sure there are kits other than `n`?

Comment: I need update column 'qtde' where eg. 'stock_id' = 13 AND tamanho = 's'

Comment: Is `size` a string like S, M, X, or a number like 1 or 10?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: *"I need update column 'qtde' where eg. 'stock_id' = 13 AND tamanho = 's'"* - Add an additional clause with the `AND` operator.

Comment: @Barmar 'size' it's a column with values S, M, X and 'qtde' it's another column with number 1 to 10

Comment: So should it be `SET qtde` instead of `SET size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other condition with `AND` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE stock_table SET qtde = IF(kit = \'n\', 1, (1 * 10)) WHERE size = \'S\' AND id = '.$row->stock_id);
```

BTW, if `$row` is the result of another query, you can use `UPDATE + JOIN` to do this in one query, instead of looping. See [MySQL update table based on another tables value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394506/mysql-update-table-based-on-another-tables-value)

Comment: Return erro, Unknown column 's' in 'where clause'

UPDATE stock_table SET qtde = (qtde +1) WHERE size = p AND id = 10. But, s its a row of size column

Comment: I forgot to escape the quotes around `S`. But that should have caused a PHP syntax error, not a SQL error.

Comment: You right, I have tested with this adjust and work fine. Thank you.