# SQL newbie question - trying to set a value where two columns match and another column has another value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to set the value of a column 'VALUE' where the 'ID' equals 2 AND the 'USERID' matches another row in the same table, where the 'ID' equals 1 and the VALUE is, say, 'London' in the example...

So:

```
ID | USERID | VALUE

1  | 1      | London
1  | 2      | Madrid
1  | 3      | London
1  | 4      | Paris
2  | 1      | null
2  | 2      | null
2  | 3      | null
2  | 4      | null
```

Becomes

```
ID | USERID | VALUE

1  | 1      | London
1  | 2      | Madrid
1  | 3      | London
1  | 4      | Paris
2  | 1      | on
2  | 2      | null
2  | 3      | on
2  | 4      | null
```

Is this possible?

If anyone can help I would be most grateful! Thanks.

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394506/mysql-update-table-based-on-another-tables-value

Comment: Thank-you so much @Barmar Apologies for making a rookie error. I promise I have tried looking for some time, but I was struggling to find the correct place to start - your links have helped tremendously to get me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use a `join` in an `update`:

```
update t join
       t t2
       on t2.userid = t.userid and t2.value = 'London'
    set value = 'on'
    where t.id = 1
```

Comment: Inicidentally, does using `AS` to declare the alias detract from something/anything other than readability for a beginner?

Comment: @AndrewMorton . . . This doesn't use `as`.  I use it for column aliases - there is a small advantage if you use it well because it can help spot missing commas.  I don't use it for table aliases because I find no use for it.  But there is no harm in using it.