# SQL updating a table, using information from another table, that has just been entered

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a GUI where I can add sales to a table SALES. It takes in an EmployeeID and StoreID. When I add a sale, I'd like the SaleAmount to be added to the employee (EMPLOYEE Table) and the store (STORE Table)associated with the sale. I have had no luck searching this elsewhere.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQLite, SQL-Server? Doing an update with data from a different table is different in each.

Comment: DDL - create an insert trigger to do it ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394506/mysql-update-table-based-on-another-tables-value for MySQL

Comment: @Barmar I'm using MySQL, apologies!