# MySQL with JOIN in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table (history_price) with 2 columns (asset_id and volume) with a lot of NULL lines that I want to fill.

1- I have the following to identify the NULL

```
    mycursor.execute(f"SELECT `Ticker`,`Price`,`Quantity` FROM `history_price` WHERE `volume` IS NULL;")
```

2- I have the following to find asset_id for each ticker

```
    mycursor.execute(f"SELECT `asset_id`  FROM `param_asset` WHERE `param_asset`.`Ticker` LIKE '{ticker}';")
    for y in mycursor:
        result = y[0]
        return result
```

3- I have the following to fill asset_id

```
    mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO `history_price` (asset_id) VALUES (%s)",
```

4- I have the following to calculate the volume

```
    volume = float(price) * float(quantity)
```

5-I have the following to insert the volume in the table

```
    mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO `history_price` (volume) VALUES (%s)",
```

Right now they are running as multiple queries in multiple loops, but I am sure I can just join the tables, calculate and fill in one single neat query... Help please

Comment: I don't see how these are related. The two `INSERT` queries create different rows.

Comment: Please post your current loop that executes these statements, so we can see how you're passing results from the `select` into the `INSERT` statements.

Comment: If you want to fill in NULL values in existing rows you should be using `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394506/mysql-update-table-based-on-another-tables-value

Comment: What is the point of having both `asset_id` and `Ticker` as identifiers? As `hp.volume` is just `hp.price * hp.quantity`, perhaps it would be better to add it as a generated column instead of storing it redundantly?

Comment: UPDATE `History` SET `History`.`volume` = (`History`.`Price` * History`.`Quantity`) WHERE `History`.`volume` IS NULL was the most efficient way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE History 
SET History.volume = (History.Price * History.Quantity)
WHERE History.volume IS NULL
```

was the most efficient way to do it

Comment: Where is `param_asset` in this?

Comment: Why did you change table names? What happened to `history_price`?

Comment: Sorry , I should not have changed the table nalme for clarity purposes.
I wanted to do to many things at once. I have simplified it with 2 different actions. On one end the (History.Price * History.Quantity) for the volume, and the volume * exchange rate for the EUR